# django inline admin: dynamically delete non-model fields from model form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

When I display a user profile inline in the admin, I want to delete some non-model fields based on certain conditions.

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    form = ProfileForm
    max_num = 1
    can_delete = False
```

The ProfileForm has some additional fields, which are not related to the model and I want to delete them under certain conditions, e.g. a certain user is editing the form.

I tried to explicitly set the fields to include and I also tried to exclude the fields with the help of get_formset():

```
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['fields'] = ['fieldX', 'fieldY']
        #kwargs['exclude'] = ['fieldZ']
        return super(ProfileInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

It works fine with model fields, but the non-model fields are always shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but I think I can help.

You can hide the fields using the **fieldsets** property of the ModelAdmin class.

Just lists the fields that you want to show.